# Lost files after hard shutdown then booted to windows

Tags: dual-boot, 23.04, data-loss

I lost files in a shared partition ( NTFS),
I forced shutdown then booted from windown, when come back to ubuntu I found that a whole directory disappeared, not found in trash also.

Comment: Forced shutdown often damages file system. And if Windows fast start up is on, Windows restores the hibernated set of data, and anything written outside of the hibernation is lost. Make sure Windows fast start up is off & do not force shutdown as write may not be complete.

Comment: it seems that data on NTFS partition disappears after reboot